# Error: 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full

Tags: sql-server, filegroups

We have increased disk space on the SQL Server, and there is definitely enough space on the server, yet below error is raised:

> com.softmar.fileserver.WebFileException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.WebFileImage'.'pkWebFileImage' in database 'sslFileServer' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

The properties of the database shows that there is only 1.1 MB available, yet other databases on the same SQL server shows much more space available on the properties.  So why is only this database not accommodating the disk size increase?  Looking at the file settings it is set to unrestricted growth.

This is rather critical so will appreciate your swift response.

[image]

Comment: You freed up space on the drive, but how much space did you free up? What is the current size of the file? What is the autogrowth setting?

Comment: [This may help you out](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/33702/10414)

Comment: The autogrowth setting is: 1024 MB, unrestricted growth.  There are two relevant databases on the particular SQL server.  The one database is perfectly fine in terms of space, but this particular database seems to be stuck on the available space.  So it's like it's not refreshing?  Running sp_spaceused on the database yields the following results: database_size: 98792.5MB | unallocated space: 1.88 MB | reserved: 100113024 KB | data: 100097224 KB | index_size: 1048 KB | unused: 14752 KB

Comment: Can you post the results of this query:  `USE sslFileServer;
GO
SELECT d.name
 , mf.name
 , mf.physical_name
 , Size = mf.size * 8192E0 / 1048576
 , MaxSize = mf.max_size * 8192E0 / 1048576
 , Growth = mf.growth * 8192E0 / 1048576
FROM master.sys.databases d
 INNER JOIN master.sys.master_files mf ON d.database_id = mf.database_id
WHERE d.name = DB_NAME()
ORDER BY d.name
 , mf.type
 , mf.name;
`

Comment: So the data file needs to grow by 1 GB. Is there more than 1 GB available on that database's disk?

Comment: Comment below from the relevant DBA: We allocated the 130GB to the storage drive for the server after the sytem was reporting the low storage.
Pls keep in mind that its not just a physical machine with harddrives, but attached to a storage solution. So we could increase the allocated storage, but somehow the windows server OS did not really recognize it yet.

Answer (score -2):

add a file to your database and set it's filegroup to primary.