# Locate the file that a given non-clustered index is stored on?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Is there a query to view which file a given non-clustered index is stored on?

Comment: Just taking a step back, what are you trying to solve by figuring this out?

Comment: Are you talking file or filegroup?

Comment: Saw a user screen shot of app error saying that index IX_FOO could not allocate space in database BAR.  Trying to find the underlying file that is out of space.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primary filegroup is full SQL Server 2008](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33700/primary-filegroup-is-full-sql-server-2008) the error message should indicate the file group you need to worry about-- `PRIMARY` or otherwise